# Random variables regarding a vector space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, vector-spaces, random-variables, expectation

[image]

This is an exercise I am stuck at. I can understand the meanings of the random variables Y_1, Y_2...etc. However I am stuck at how to compute the expected value of those random variables... Could anyone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of questions: they aren't appropriate for this site as they aren't search engine friendly.

Comment: Hint: you can use this formula for the expectation of a $\mathbb N$-valued random variable: $EK = \sum_{k\ge0} P(K>k)$.

Comment: @kimchi lover Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Explain the formula, or explain its use?

Comment: Here is a use in your kind of situation. Let $K$ be the number of vectors you need to collect to have full rank.  It suffices to work out a formula for the chance that a collection of $k$ vectors does not have full rank, for in that situation, $K>k$.

Comment: Could you give a full solution if possible? I tried to figure out the hint, but I think I can't grasp how to compute the expected values...